# Is it possible to query the Import Queue with SOQL?

Tags: soql, import, data-import-wizard, asyncapexjob

I would like to run a SOQL query and get the status of a particular import job. I'm referring to the Import Queue found at:

> Administration Setup > Monitoring > Imports

I looked in `AsyncApexJobs` but that does not appear to track this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it were a custom import process that leveraged batched apex then sure - but the provided import wizard jobs I'd be very confident the answer is no.